# How to Get Fixed Children to Play Nicely with their Parents

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get the blue `#block` to animate with the rest of the document when the `#menu` slides in/out?

**Menu off screen with the default block position:**

[image: Menu off screen with the default block position]

**Menu on screen with the block *incorrectly* position:**

[image: Menu on screen with the block incorrectly position]

**Menu on screen with the block *correctly* positioned:**

[image: Menu on screen with the block correctly positioned]

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button>Menu Toggle</button>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="block"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: orange;
}

#container {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500vh;
    width: 500px;
}

#block {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    if ( $('#menu').hasClass('active') ) {
        menuOut();
    } else {
        menuIn();
    }
});

function menuIn() {
    $('#menu').addClass('active').animate({'left':'0'});
    $('body').animate({'left': '200px'});
}

function menuOut() {
    $('#menu').removeClass('active').animate({'left':'-200px'});
    $('body').animate({'left': '0'});
}
```

**A few notes:**

- `#block` is nested inside `#container`, but since its position is fixed it won't move with the `body` animation.
- Whenever the browser is resized `#block` realigns itself correctly within `#container`

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pa634x8p/1/

---

Follow up, I solved this by calculating the positioning of the `#block` and animating it from there.

http://jsfiddle.net/pa634x8p/3/

However, if there's a simpler way to accomplish this I'd still love to know.

Comment: "Fixed children to play nicely with their parents"? *chuckle* (SCNR)

Comment: The title of this question is a little weird :)

Comment: Upon reading the title, I thought I was in the [link](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It does describe the problem, but yeah it was supposed to be a little "*cough*" creative.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `position:relative` to #container and a `position:absolute` and `left:0` to #block
Then, calculate the top position of #block element with setTop() function, on document ready, on window resize and on window scroll:

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/pa634x8p/2/)

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
if ( $('#menu').hasClass('active') ) {
    menuOut();
} else {
    menuIn();
}
});

 function menuIn() {
$('#menu').addClass('active').animate({'left':'0'});
$('body').animate({'left': '200px'});
}

function menuOut() {
$('#menu').removeClass('active').animate({'left':'-200px'});
$('body').animate({'left': '0'});
}

var setTop = function() {
var block = $('#block');
var height = $(window).height();
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var top = (parseInt(height) - 100) + parseInt(scroll);
console.log(top);
block.css({'top':top + 'px'});    
}
setTop();

$(window).resize(function() {
setTop();
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
setTop();
});
```

Comment: Nice one, that definitely works! I just came up with a similar approach attacking it from the "side" instead of the "top" http://jsfiddle.net/pa634x8p/3/

Comment: Accepting this answer because it works, although I'm going to go with my own solution. Thanks for the help. :)